# Can Python Closure store and change an external scalar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures

environment: Python 3.7.5

I was trying to understand closure in Python, so I made following attempts:

First, I wrote a function which generate functions to change a vector I initiated:

```
def outer(c=[0,0]):
    
    def inner(x):
        nx = c[0] + x[0]
        ny = c[1] + x[1]
        c[0] = nx
        c[1] = ny
        return c
    
    return inner
```

Here are the result I got:

```
>>> p = outer()
>>> p([1,2])
[1, 2]
>>> p([1,2])
[2, 4]
>>> p([1,2])
[3, 6]
```

It worked well, the inner function stored the vector every step so that the vector can change gradually

Then, I wrote a similar function, only change vector c to a scalar:

```
def outer(c=0):
    
    def inner(x):
        nx = c + x
        c = nx
        return c
    
    return inner
```

However this time I cannot run it:

```
>>> p = outer()
>>> p(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
    p(1)
  File "C:/Users/thisi/Desktop/21345.py", line 5, in inner
    nx = c + x
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment
```

I wonder why python cannot find variable 'c' this time? And why the first case work?

Comment: This behaviour is nothing specific to closures - it's just how Python handles scope. (And yes it is a little confusing if you come from other languages which have explicit variable declarations.)

Answer (score 3):

Use `nonlocal c` to have desired effect. The first case works because you don't change `c` directly, you assign to contents of `c`, which is of type list.

```
def outer(c=0):

    def inner(x):
        nonlocal c   # <-- note `nonlocal`
        nx = c + x
        c = nx
        return c

    return inner

p = outer()
print( p(1) )
print( p(1) )
```

Prints:

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are any assignment statements to a variable inside a function, then that variable is in the function's local scope (if not explicitly declared `nonlocal`).

Consider this code:

```
def outer(c=0):
    
    def inner(x):
        if False: c = 0
        return c + x
    
    return inner

func = outer(3)
print(func(2))
```

This will give an `UnboundLocalError` even though the assignment `c = 0` is never executed.  But if the line with the assignment is removed entirely, then it will run.

In the list example, the variable `c` is not assigned anywhere in `inner`; it is only modified using item assignment.